# FTP Publish with Visual Studio 2017 missing

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, publish, visual-studio-2017

I recently upgraded to 2017. When I try to publish a web site with the Visual Studio FTP publish option, I get `The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed.`

Any idea how to install these components ?

Comment: Which workloads or components do you have installed?

Comment: Also, under your %DevEnvDir%, do you have a bunch of files named Rebex.*?

Comment: I have just the web apps tool and Xamarin installed. I use it for MVC 5 mostly and apps

Comment: No Rebex either

Comment: Hm, those assemblies should be installed in the same component as the project system.  In other words, if you can open your project, those assemblies *should* be there.  Have you tried doing a repair or possibly a reinstall? (I hate to suggest that but...)

Comment: tried a full reinstall. Very strange. Have not been able to publish with VS2017

Comment: Ok, this is a total hack, but you could install VS2015 Express or Community editions and copy those assemblies to the VS2017 install folder.  Well, I don't know how licensing applies in this case, but it should be the same assembly so I don't think anyone would complain.

Comment: interesting idea...I'll try it.

Comment: Is your publish now working? If so any suggestions? Mine doesn't and I am sure it's an add-on or something I have done wrong. See my question in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975559/visual-studio-2017-not-able-to-see-publish-missing-profile-deployment-opti