# Visual Studio 2017 - Not Able to see Publish - Missing Profile / Deployment Options

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am not able to publish any project any more. Am I missing a NuGet Package or something. I have the latest VS 2017 (March 2017). See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem I re-enabled "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" with the Extensions and Updates.

Comment: Why is this the case when I don't even use Azure?! What is Microsoft thinking... I can guess though! Well done it worked.

Comment: In VS 2017 I had to enable "Microsoft VisualStudio Managed Publish" to get "Publish" in project context menu

Comment: @Poma Where exactly? Tools | Options?

Comment: I think it was an extension, but I don't see it in my extension list now, maybe it got integrated in VS

Comment: @Rob How did you solved it? I have the same problem but I have not azure, I just simply publish my project into C: Drive path and after with FTP upload into the server. But now not show publish button? Why?Please help

Comment: @BrijeshMavani install Azure!! Without it, you cannot publish anything.

Comment: Could find it list in the extensions.  I am currently using VS2017 and just seeing this problem in one solution, other solutions worked fine.  This one was re-engineered for an old assembly (grim).